# connection error while trying to connect mssql database to node js backend using knex

Tags: node.js, sql-server, knex.js, tedious

I recently cloned my existing node backend repo that worked properly about 3 months ago but now I can't connect my neither local nor remote MSSQL DB while I'm trying to call my endpoint in locally deployed backend below error occurred. I could use MSSM (Microsoft SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT) to connect to my DB using same credentials

[image: Error while trying to connect local SQL server]

[image: Error while trying to connect remote SQL server]

These are the dependencies of my project

[image: Dependencies]

My Tedious connection config object

[image: config object]

Environment variables (.env file)

[image: env]

I have tried upgrading my dependencies to latest, enabling TCP/IP of SQL server, also tried remote MSSQL server, tried to deploy and call the endpoint in different machine neither of them worked for me always the same error throw form backend.

Comment: Please share more information. Where is your mssql running? Local? Docker? Share your configFiles (local only) and the code where the error occours.

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74886403/edit) your question to include the Tedious connection config object. When the error message says it's failing to connect to `"localhost",:1433` with extra quotes `"` and commas `,` then it seems there's something odd going on there.

Comment: @Ralle initially I was running mssql on my computer locally, because of the error I tried remote mssql server that hosts in cloudclusters.io but the same error was occurred.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning cause comment I tried to remove my environment variables and instead of that I hardcoded credentials into my JS code now it's working fine, have you any idea what cause for that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the Docker documentation, [Declare default environment variables in file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/):

> Each line represents a key-value pair. Values can optionally be quoted.
>
> - `VAR=VAL` -> `VAL`
> - `VAR="VAL"` -> `VAL`
> - `VAR='VAL'` -> `VAL`

You will notice that there are no comma `,` characters in the examples. Instead of your `.env` file containing the following:

```
DB_HOST="localhost",
DB_USER="admin",
DB_PASSWORD="Admin123",
```

It should contain the following instead (note: no commas):

```
DB_HOST="localhost"
DB_USER="admin"
DB_PASSWORD="Admin123"
```

Comment: Thanks mate this worked for me, I was such an idiot to not find out that again thank you for your valuable time